# Stopping broadcast propagation from parent to child controller in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, broadcast, angularjs-scope

Is there a way to stop the propagation of a broadcast from parent to child controller?

Parent:

```
$scope.$on('event', function() {
     //stop propagation
})
```

Child:

```
$scope.$on('event', function() {
    //only fired by this controller scope
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, it was easy.

```
if (ev.targetScope.$id != ev.currentScope.$id) {
    return
}
```